# How to add "Maven Managed Depenencies" for a simple java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I created a simple Java project (NOT a maven project) in Eclipse. How can I add "Maven Managed Dependencies" to it?

I tried to right click the project node. There's no "Maven" option in the right click menu. And there's no POM.xml file.

[image]

Comment: If there is no pom.xml, then there are no Maven managed dependencies. What do you expect to be in that list?

Comment: Edit the `.project` file and add the Maven nature line. And add a POM.

Comment: @CoverosGene I am wondering if there's some easy way to auto create a pom.xml from my project.

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Thanks but I prefer some automatic way. And btw, the nature is specified like this `<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple project in `New` --> `Other` --> `Maven Project`

[image]

If your project is a simple java project, you can convert it. Right click on project, `Configure` --> `Convert to Maven Project`:

[image]

Enter the details to create the pom file.

[image]

After that, you can add dependencies by right click on project, `Maven` --> `Add Dependency`, or just add dependency in the generated `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks! The second approach is what I need. And it works. BTW, the `Maven Dependencies` node will not show up until there's some dependencies added. To add dependencies do just as Bruno said last.